# "It's standing in the front": describing position of objects in line

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

In our school, the school buses are parked in a line, from where the children board their respective buses.( according to where they live). So if someone has to tell about the position like the first bus, second, third ....... last bus etc., how can it be expressed naturally?

### The first bus:

> 1.)L-1 stands in the front.
>
> 2.)L-1 is the first bus.

### Second, Third and so on (except for the last bus)

> 3.)L-2 stands behind L-1.
>
> 4.)L-9 is the second last bus.
>
> 5.)L-9 is the second bus from the last.

### Last bus:

> 6.) L-10 is the last bus.
>
> 7.) L-10 stands at the back.
>
> 8) L-10 stands in the last.

Do all of these sentences sound natural? If not how should they be used so that they sound natural?

**P.S.: Can "stand" be used with buses or should  "parked" be used?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Stand* should not be used for a bus. *Parked* is perfect in this case.

The most natural way to direct someone to the exact bus you're talking about would be:

- **First**: L-1 is the first bus. *or* L-1 is in the front. *or* L-1 is at the very front.
- **Second & So On**: L-2 is second from the front; L-9 is the second to last bus
- **Last**: L-10 is parked in the back. *or* L-10 is the last bus. *or* L-10 is in the very back.

Comment: Can't "from" be used in this sentence:"L-9 is the second bus from the last." Or should it be only "to" ,as in your sentence?

Comment: And the sentences  including "front" and "back" are according to the positions of the buses in a line and not to the things around them, right? Like "front" has been used with respect to other buses in the line? AND the same goes for "back"?